# Issues using a 2D Raycast to detect mouse hover on object colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Im currently working on a 2D character selection screen in Unity that should operate similarly to the Mortal Kombat character selection screen. Currently, I have a class called `CharacterSelector` attached to the main camera. The class holds methods for selection/deselection of characters, hover events, and selection confirmation. I was able to use a `RayCast2D` to build my character selection method; however, I am running into issues using it for hover events.

In my scene, I have a group of character images that the player can choose from (if they are unlocked). When the player hovers over the character with his/her mouse, the character image should be surrounded by a yellow border. When the user clicks on the desired character, a larger version of the image will popup to the left of the character image group.

Right now, I have the following code for the hover method:

```
    public void onHover(Ray ray, RaycastHit2D hit)
    {
        if(hit.collider == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("nothing hit");

        }            
        if (Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            print(hit.collider.name);
        }
    }
```

This method belongs to a class that the `CharacterSelection` class inherits from. The following is on the `CharacterSelection` class:

```
class CharacterSelector : Selector
{
    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit2D hit;        

    public void Start()
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        onHover(ray, hit); 

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {                               
            selectCharacter();
        }
    }                   
}
```

Also, all the character images that I am trying to hover over currently have 2D Box Colliders. As of right now, I am unable to get hover operation to work. It does not print the name of the character image to the console. I am using this as a first step to see if Unity recognizes the character image or not. Let me know if I can provide additional information!

Comment: So what is your problem? What's  working and what's not? You left that one out...

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. When the player hovers over one of the character images nothing happens and nothing is printed to the console. It should print the name of the character image name so I know unity can actually see it. Once I have that going, I will add the border around the image.

Comment: Ok. Are the characters displayed with `Image` component with `Canvas` or `Sprite`(SpriteRender)?

Comment: Are your colliders "is trigger" ticked ?

Comment: It is with Sprite and the "is trigger" is ticked, are there any other settings I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse changes position on screen almost every frame. This means your ray should be updated every frame according to mouse position. So I moved the corresponding statement from Start() to Update();

```
class CharacterSelector : Selector
{
    Ray ray;    
    RaycastHit2D hit;   

    public void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        onHover(ray, hit); 

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {                               
            selectCharacter();
        }
    }                   
}
```

Secondly, if you look in [the definition of Physics2D.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) you'll find that it gives you back the RaycastHit2D object. This is the object you should check the collider of, not your hit object which should have thrown an NullReferenceException, I don't know why it didn't. So this:

```
public void onHover(Ray ray, RaycastHit2D hit)
{
    hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity);
    if(hit.collider == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("nothing hit");

    }            
    else
    {
        print(hit.collider.name);
    }
}
```

Apart from this you don't really need the hit argument in onHover() function, it can be a local variable in the function. But if you are planning on using your hit variable in CharacterSelector script than you should change the declaration of onHover to: `onHover(Ray ray, out RaycastHit2D hit)` the `out` keyword passes the variable by reference instead of a copy of its value.

Also, I think checking if mouse is hovering over an object shouldn't be done in onHover, it's kinda misleading and doesn't seem logical to me. I'd move the body of onHover to another function like RaycastChecker(). I'd call onHover() only if mouse is actually hovering over the sprite. (like in OnCollisionEnter you take it granted that the collision did happen, so should the onHover, I think)

Comment: Forgot to comment, this worked perfectly! Thanks for your help and the detailed explaination